# freebsd post-installation issues

Tags: installation, freebsd, xorg

I've installed freeBSD 8.2 and now trying to get GUI working. I did install KDE and related packages from `sysinstall`.

On bootup, at shell prompt, when I do `X` or `Xorg`, screen goes blank and I cannot even get back to prompt.

How can I see what is going wrong? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> to switch to the virtual console **1**. thats where you launched your xserver.

see whats going wrong: check /var/log/X*.log

and normally you would launch a xsession from console via `startx` (and not with a pure `X`, which just launches the xserver and nothing else, not even a windowmanager).

Comment: cool, thanks for responding. I will give this a try.